# shell script to sum column with if else

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I would like to sum the second column of a CSV file.

I used the code below:

```
awk -F'#' '{c+=$2}END{printf "count=%d\n",c}' file.csv
```

It works perfectly. 
Now I would like to add `ifelse` condition to it. 
I would like to sum column 2 only if colum 3 = 'A' and Column 4 = 'B'

I add an `ifelse` clause but it doesn't work

```
awk -F'#' 'if [ "$3" == 'A' && "$4" == 'B' ]; then c+=$2; fi
END{printf "count=%d\n",c}' file.csv
```

Comment: You are mixing constructs from `Awk` and `shell` together.

Comment: Yes. I am noob on shell and Linux function. I only want to sum the second column with if clause. is that possible ?

Comment: Post some sample data please.

Comment: Read Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to learn awk, and Shell Scripting Recipes by Chris Johnson to learn shell. They are 2 completely different tools, each with their own purpose and syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing constructs from `Awk` and `bash` together. Assuming you want an `if-else` clause in `Awk` you need to do,

```
awk -F'#' '$3 == "A" && $4 == "B"{c+=$2;} END{printf "count=%d\n",c}' file.csv
count=41
```

for a sample input I produced as

```
$ cat file.csv
junk#21#A#B
junk#22#C#D
junk#20#A#B
junk#19#D#E
```

i.e. the statment `'$3 == "A" && $4 == "B"` implicitly means do the action of sum calculation only if `$3` equals `A` and `$4` equals `B`

Explicit usage of `if` can be done as something below,

```
awk -F'#' '{if ($3 == "A" && $4 == "B") {c+=$2;}} END{printf "count=%d\n",c}' file
count=41
```

---

It is *NOT* recommended to use a pure `bash` script for parsing/looping over files, but for mere practice if you want a way, you can do something like

```
#!/bin/bash

unset count 
# The '_' in read implies ignore rest of the line
while IFS='#' read -r  col1 col2 col3 col4 _
do
    [[ "$col3" == "A" && "$col4" == "B" ]] && ((count+=col2))
    # Here the '[[' implies the if-clause and '&&' implies do on true condition
done<file

printf "%d\n" "$count"
```

Comment: It is typically not recommended for performance: bash is  horrifically slow

Comment: ....and horrifically difficult to get the syntax right for text processing sine the default behaviors are designed to ease process and file manipulation, NOT text processing. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)